# Multiple Arrays from Text File

Tags: java, arrays

I'm stumbled. I'm working on a project for class and for the life of me I can't figure out to create multiple arrays from a text file. I've been checking around but most methods I've read up have inconcise. I'm able to procure the file into an array succesfully but trying to create an array via hasNext and nextLine just gives me null data. Any pointers?

```
public static void main (String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {  
    int count = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    String inputfile = "input.txt";
    File filename = new File (inputfile);
    Scanner console = new Scanner(filename);   
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (console.hasNext()) {
        list.add(console.nextLine());
    }

    Scanner user = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Please verify file before moving forward.");
    String fileverify = user.nextLine();
    String line = "";

    if (fileverify.equals("input.txt")) {
        System.out.println("File is available.\n");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Wrong file. Please try again.");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(list);

    String[] studentNames = new String [count];
    int[]studentIDs = new int[count];
    double[]studentScores = new double[count];
    count++;

    while(console.hasNext()){

        studentNames[count] = console.nextLine();
        studentIDs[count] = console.nextInt();
        studentScores[count] = console.nextDouble();

    }

    System.out.println("Would you like to:\n" +
                        "\n1. Print average" +
                        "\n2. Print high score"+
                        "\n3. Print low score"+
                        "\n4. Print median"+
                        "\n5. Print all student names and scores"+
                        "\n6. Exit\n");
    String command = user.next(); 

    int nextInt = console.nextInt();
    if (user.equals("1")){
          count++;
          sum = sum + console.nextInt();
          System.out.println("The average is : " + sum / count) ;
    }

}
```

Text file looks like this.

```
Class size 37
Leland Fitzgerald:83629:94.7
Marilyn A. Stanley:91602:18.8
Sergio Jones:24914:96.4
Mona Hines:62909:30.6
Brian Little:12713:17.7
Iris Logan:84645:97.8
Alonzo Strickland:2913:19.7
Edith Richards:78585:53.9
Marianne Wheeler:30544:77.0
Viola Walton:76264:78.2
Lyle Houston:7617:70.0
Sheldon Jim Ford:53185:29.0
Ivan Carlson:40732:84.5
Aaron Ramsey:12392:71.3
Katherine Townsend:30999:34.9
Wilbert Vargas:76095:01.9
Erick Gibson:47420:98.9
Audrey Ward:32662:88.9
Lynda Cain:48951:88.7
Allison Patrick:72177:61.6
Cecelia Griffith:14614:08.5
Monique Mccoy:711:85.3
Maureen Alvarado:14961:00.1
Holly Morris:77959:26.5
Justin Parks:48615:40.0
Ellis Mcbride:26184:35.4
Forrest Weber:12330:84.3
Myron Blake:77705:78.7
Bob Goodman:31072:77.9
Jon Foster:12913:76.4
Alexis Zimmerman:76866:24.2
Melissa Warner:85395:70.8
Rodolfo Moreno:32141:92.6
Leah Maxwell:49734:39.5
Sandy Carpenter:36441:43.5
Kara Robertson:26797:88.8
Shelly Casey:65599:67.6
```

Comment: Can you clarify what output you're trying to get? Is it an array of lines, where each line is an array of the words of that line?

Comment: Not trying trying to get an array of lines. More so I'm just trying to get the array (text file) loaded into the compiler the data so I can output it as noted in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope what you need to achieve is to read a file then, add each line to an `ArrayList` of `String` type and split each `ArrayList` element to three different arrays and manipulate data based those arrays, if that's the case

1. Do your file verification before reading the file.

   ```
   String inputfile = "input.txt";
   File filename = new File (inputfile);

   Scanner user = new Scanner (System.in);
   System.out.println("Please verify file before moving forward.");
   String fileverify = user.nextLine();

   if (fileverify.equals("input.txt")) {
       System.out.println("File is available.\n");
   }
   else {
       System.out.println("Wrong file. Please try again.");
       return;
   }

   Scanner console = new Scanner(filename);   
   ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   while (console.hasNext()) {
       list.add(console.nextLine());
   }
   ```
2. Declare arrays with the same size of your list

   ```
   String[] studentNames = new String [list.size()];
   int[] studentIDs = new int[list.size()];
   double[] studentScores = new double[list.size()];
   ```

> I won't recommend this because sometimes list can have a size that
>   array won't accept.

3. Iterate the `ArrayList` to add elements to array

   ```
   for(String line : list) {

      String[] lineSplitArray = line.split(":");
      studentNames[count] = lineSplitArray[0];
      studentIDs[count] = Integer.parseInt(lineSplitArray[1]);
      studentScores[count] = Double.parseDouble(lineSplitArray[2]);
      count++;
   }
   ```

All the above explanation is done based on my assumption about your problem. Sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: It appears you didn't handle the overhead information (the first line of info).